# Laravel : Find all sales and leads per user between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm having trouble putting this all together in a nice view to show all User's Sales and Leads they have during the week.

Users has many Leads and has many Sales.

Tables: Users(id), Leads(user_id), Sales(user_id)

In Report blade display table headers:

User / Total Leads per Week / Total Sales per Week

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Leads</th>
            <th>Sales</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Jon Doe</td>
          <td>157</td>
          <td>45</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jane Dozer</td>
          <td>183</td>
          <td>67</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to combine these queries so I can output on blade datatable report properly listing all users Sales and Leads. My JOIN attempts are not working!

````
$sales = Sale::where('user_id', '=', '$userId')->whereBetween('sale_date', [$startDate, $endDate])->get();

or

SELECT count(*) AS total_sales FROM sales WHERE user_id = '1' AND sale_date BETWEEN '2022-01-03' and '2022-01-07'```

$leads = Lead::where('user_id', '=', '$userId')->whereBetween('lead_date', [$startDate, $endDate])->get();```

or

SELECT count(*) AS total_leads FROM sales WHERE user_id = '1' AND lead_date BETWEEN '2022-01-03' and '2022-01-07'
````

Thanks for helping me visualize this better!!

Comment: what about creating a view and then fetching records from view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically used RAW sql queries for all of it...

```
$users_team = DB::SELECT("SELECT 
    users.id, 
    users.full_name, 
    (SELECT count(*) FROM leads
                WHERE leads.user_id = users.id
                AND call_date BETWEEN $startDate AND $endDate
            ) AS total_leads,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM clients
                WHERE clients.user_id = users.id
                AND app_date BETWEEN $startDate AND $endDate
            ) AS total_sales,
    (SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(time_to_sec(talktime))) FROM talktimes
                WHERE talktimes.user_id = users.id
                AND date_logged BETWEEN $startDate AND $endDate
            ) AS total_talktime
FROM users 
RIGHT JOIN activations ON users.id = activations.user_id
WHERE users.team_id = '$myLocation' ORDER BY users.full_name ASC");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `UNION ALL` to combine two queries into a single result set.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_leads 
FROM sales 
WHERE user_id = '1' AND lead_date BETWEEN '2022-01-03' AND '2022-01-07'

UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_sales 
FROM sales 
WHERE user_id = '1' AND sale_date BETWEEN '2022-01-03' AND '2022-01-07'
```

In your case, I would use `OR` to combine two conditions.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_leads 
FROM sales 
WHERE user_id = '1' 
  AND (lead_date BETWEEN '2022-01-03' AND '2022-01-07'
       OR
       sale_date BETWEEN '2022-01-03' AND '2022-01-07')
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code block probably will solve the issue without leaving the Laravel Eloquent.

```php
$results = [];
$users = User::all(['id', 'full_name']);

foreach($users as $user) {
    $total_sales = Sale::where('user_id', $user->id)
        ->whereBetween('sale_date', [$startDate, $endDate])
        ->get('id')
        ->count();

    $total_leads = Lead::where('user_id', $user->id)
        ->whereBetween('lead_date', [$startDate, $endDate])
        ->get('id')
        ->count();

    $results[] = [
        'full_name' => $user->full_name,
        'total_sales' => $total_sales,
        'total_leads' => $total_leads,
    ];
}
```